# close pygtk dialog window after it was used

Tags: events, user-interface, fork, pygtk, wrapper

I am currently writing a wrapper for a small console program I wrote.
The c program needs a password string as input and because I intend to use it through dmenu and such, I'd like to use a little gtk entry box to enter that string.
However, I have to fork after I get the input (because I'm also handling clipboard stuff which needs deletion after some time) and the window simply won't close until the child process exits.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from gi.repository import Gtk
import sys
import os
import time
import getpass

HELP_MSG = "foobar [options] <profile>"

class EntryDialog(Gtk.Dialog):

    def run(self):
        result = super(EntryDialog, self).run()
        if result == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
            text = self.entry.get_text()
        else:
            text = None
        return text

    def __init__(self):
        super(EntryDialog, self).__init__()
        entry = Gtk.Entry()
        entry.set_visibility(False)
        entry.connect("activate", 
                      lambda ent, dlg, resp: 
                          dlg.response(resp), 
                          self, 
                          Gtk.ResponseType.OK)
        self.vbox.pack_end(entry, True, True, 0)
        self.vbox.show_all()
        self.entry = entry

def get_pwd():
    if sys.stdin.isatty():
        return getpass.getpass()
    else:
        prompt = EntryDialog()
        prompt.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
        passwd = prompt.run()
        prompt.destroy()
        return passwd
```

The thought is, that it should close when I hit enter, but I'm pretty sure I'm doing something entirely wrong. 
The script basically continues like this:

```
profile = argv[0]
pwd = get_pwd()

if pwd is None:
    print(HELP_MSG)
    sys.exit()

out = doStuff()
text_to_clipboard(out)

# now fork and sleep!
if os.fork():
    sys.exit()

time.sleep(10)

clear_clipboard()

sys.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I dropped the python wrapper and wrote it directly in c. However, for anyone having the same problem, the (untested) solution would be to add a function

```
def quit():
    self.emit("destroy")
```

where 'self' is the dialog box - and connect that to the "activate" signal,

```
entry.connect("activate", quit)
```

so that the dialog widget emits the destroy signal as soon as the user hits Return and thus Gtk.main_quit gets called.
In c the content can be extracted nicely by specifying a GtkEntryBuffer and calling it's

```
gtk_entry_buffer_get_text()
```

I didn't find it right now, but there is probably an equivalent for pygtk available.